# SharedLib Project not setting "UseDebugLibraries=true" in debug mode

Tags: premake

I am using premake5 alpha 6 on Windows.

The problem originated when I found that my Visual Studio project's "Runtime library" settings was set to Multi-Threaded DLL /MD in Debug mode, instead of Multi-Threaded Debug DLL (/MDd).

Upon investigation, I found that the project file Debug configuration was set to UseDebugLibraries = false. If i manually set this to true in my project file, the Debug configuration "Runtime library" setting shows correctly as /MDd.

How do i set UseDebugLibraries to true in debug mode in premake scripts?  I am doing something like below.  Note that this project is a "SharedLib"  I found that if the kind is "StaticLib" the Runtime library setting /MDd works properly.

```
project "Project"
    location "../src" 
    filename "Project_%{_ACTION or ''}" 
    kind "SharedLib"
    language "C++"                  
    pchheader "stdafx.h" 
    pchsource "../src/Project/stdafx.cpp"  

    includedirs {   
        "../include",
        "../src/Project",
    }       
    files { 
       "../src/Project/**.cpp",                    
       "../src/Project/**.h",
       "../src/Project/Project.rc"
    }      

    configuration "vs*"
        objdir "../src/Project/$(PlatformToolset)"

    configuration { "x64", "Debug" }
      defines { "_DEBUG" }
      flags { "Symbols" }

    configuration { "x64", "Release" }
      defines { "NDEBUG" }    

    configuration { "x86", "Debug" }
      defines { "_DEBUG" }
      flags { "Symbols" }     

    configuration { "x86", "Release" }
      defines { "NDEBUG" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [optimize](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/optimize) function:

- "On", "Size", "Speed", and "Full" produce `<UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>`
- "Off" and "Debug" produce `<UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>`

So you could write something like:

```
workspace "MySolution"
    configurations {"Debug", "Release"}

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        flags {"Symbols"}
        optimize "Off"
        defines {"DEBUG", "_DEBUG"}

    filter "configurations:Release"
        optimize "On"
        defines {"NDEBUG"}
```

The above uses the new [filtering system](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Filters) in premake 5.x

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i want! I knew about the optimize "On" status but didn't realize to set to "Off" for debug!